# Can someone help me explain why size value being carried?

Tags: java

in the main class  have Deque q = new Deque(5). I can insert the first int fine  but on the second insert either left or right, i get a -1 as front, when it should be 4. I debugged it but I can't seem to figure out why, has something to do with at insertLeft() where if(front == 0), size should be 5 in that case.

```
public class  Deque {
//We need to create the array and keep track of the number of items in it

private int[] array;
private int NumItems = 0; 

// keep track of the front and rear as well to help us reach our wrap around effect
private int front = -1; 
private int rear = 0; 
private int size; 

//Now we can build the constructor that create the object of Deque

    public Deque(int size){
        array = new int[size];
        
    }

    //first thing first is we need to insert but before we do that we need to check if its empty and if its full


    public boolean isEmpty(){
        
        // if it is empty, that means that front is still -1, and rear is 0 so we return front = -1 or NumItems - 1 since NumItems is 0

        return front == NumItems - 1 && rear == 0; 
        
    }

    public boolean isFull(){ 

        //if it is full, that means that front is at index zero and rear is at index NumItems - 1 so we return exactly that
        return NumItems == array.length; 
    }

    //now we can Insert either on the left or on the right

    public void insertLeft(int item){
        //first what we want to do is check if its full, here we have 3 option, if its completely full, if its completely empty, and if its neither empty or full

        if(isFull()){
            //if its full, then that means that rear is = 0 and front = NumItems - 1 so we just return "full"

            System.out.println("Full. Exceeds the allowed total of " + size + " items.");
        }
        
        if(isEmpty()){
            //if its completely empty, then we can just add it to the left at index 0, where in this case front = -1 and rear = 0 so far, but we make front also = 0, so front = rear = 0 

            front = 0; 
            rear = 0; 
        }
        
        if(front == 0){
            // in this case, its not full but not empty, just one item in it so front = 0 and so it rear. We want the wrap around so we gotta make front the "end" of the array
            front = size - 1; 
        }

        //now if front is neither a -1 (empty), 0 (one item), or = to size (full), then our next entry would be the indext right before [0 (rear), 1 , 2, 3(front)], our entry would be at 2, so what we wnat is to add at array[2] which is as simple as front - 1. 
        if(front > 0){
            front = front - 1; 
        }

        // now we can add our item into the array at index postion front where front can either be 0, -1, size - 1, front - 1
        array[front] = item; 

    }

    public void insertRight(int item){
        // we als have three factor here, if its empty, if its full, if its neither empty or full 

        if(isFull()){
            // if its full i want it to tell us it is full

            System.out.println("Full. Exceeds the allowed total of " + size + " items.");
        }

        if(isEmpty()){
            front = 0; 
            rear = 0; 
        }

        else{
            //here we just keep adding to the right first at index zero then index 1 then index 2 then rear + 1... 
            rear = rear + 1;  
        }

        if(rear == size - 1 ){
            //if we manage to reach the end of the array, to reach that wrap around effect we go back to index 0
            rear = 0; 
        }

        //now we add our item 

        array[rear] = item; 

    }
    
    public void deleteLeft(int item){
        //we would also have 3 cases, if empty nothing to delete, if full delete from front ? if in between delete from rear
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
            }
            
            //here we just move front up one, leaving the index that front was in be able to be overwritten 
            else front = front + 1; 

            // here is incase front + 1 goes past the size the array, we wrap around to index 0 again and so on
            if(front > size - 1){
                front = 0; 
            }

            
        }

    public void deleteRight(int item){
        //same thing as left in reverse
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
        }

        else{
            rear = rear - 1; 
        }

        if(rear < 0){
            rear = size - 1; 
        }


    }

    public void display(){
        return array; 
    }
```

Comment: So, just looking at the code, when you call `insertLeft`,  if `front == 0`, you do `front = size - 1; `, since `size` is `0`, this assigns `-1` to `front` ... You need to add `this.size = size;` to your constructor ... or check the `.length` of your array

Comment: @MadProgrammer it would be to wrap around. If in the main class i create an object size 5, it should carry over no ?

Comment: The array is initialised to `size`, but the instance field of the class defaults to `0`, you never assign the instance field a value ... which is why I'd use the array's `.length` property instead, saves you from things like this - it's also where some simple desk checking comes in handy

Comment: @MadProgrammer you're goated, I see what you are saying now. Thank you

Comment: Remember to format your code, there's a million newlines in it right now that don't need to be there, and you didn't properly close it off - always try to show a [mcve], in addition to the regular [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) of course.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I thought it would help to see my thought process and what my overall goal is, it's not all over the place either.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans not sure how to close tho

Comment: What do you mean with close? You can delete your post, or you can [edit] it to clean it up. Closing (i.e. as off topic, or a duplicate, or as "needing more details", etc.) is something that folks with enough rep can vote on and then if there are enough votes, the system closes the post automatically. That's not something you need to wait for as post owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make sure you're setting size when you construct the object. Add this.size to your constructor.

```
public Deque(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    array = new int[size];
}
```

You need to increment NumItems at the end of your insertRight and insertLeft methods. While we're discussing these methods there are a few things to consider. You're continuing to perform operations after you find out that the array is full. You should wrap the rest of the operations in an else block.

You are also going to get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions if you do not wrap your ifs in else statements. You do not want to check each if in the situation where one of the earlier ones is true.

As an example:

```
public void insertRight(int item) {
    if (isFull()) {
        System.out.println("Full. Exceeds the allowed total of " + size + " items.");
    } else {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            front = 0;
            rear = 0;
        } else if (rear == size - 1) {
            rear = 0;
        } else {
            rear = rear + 1;
        }
        array[rear] = item;
        NumItems++;
    }
}
```

isEmpty is going to return false when it should be true if I add 2 values then remove the 2 values. isEmpty should be:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return NumItems == 0;
}
```

I have edited the code to also make use of the display method. I'm not sure why you're returning an array to a void method but I have made it:

```
public void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NumItems; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[(front + i) % size] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here is the entire working class after I've reworked it:

```
public class Deque {
    private int[] array;
    private int NumItems = 0;
    private int front = -1;
    private int rear = 0;
    private int size;

    public Deque(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        array = new int[size];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return NumItems == 0;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return NumItems == size;
    }

    public void insertLeft(int item) {
        if (isFull()) {
            System.out.println("Full. Exceeds the allowed total of " + size + " items.");
        } else {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                front = 0;
                rear = 0;
            } else if (front == 0) {
                front = size - 1;
            } else {
                front = front - 1;
            }
            array[front] = item;
            NumItems++;
        }
    }

    public void insertRight(int item) {
        if (isFull()) {
            System.out.println("Full. Exceeds the allowed total of " + size + " items.");
        } else {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                front = 0;
                rear = 0;
            } else if (rear == size - 1) {
                rear = 0;
            } else {
                rear = rear + 1;
            }
            array[rear] = item;
            NumItems++;
        }
    }

    public void deleteLeft() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            if (front == rear) {
                front = -1;
                rear = 0;
            } else if (front == size - 1) {
                front = 0;
            } else {
                front = front + 1;
            }
            NumItems--;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
        }
    }

    public void deleteRight() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            if (front == rear) {
                front = -1;
                rear = 0;
            } else if (rear == 0) {
                rear = size - 1;
            } else {
                rear = rear - 1;
            }
            NumItems--;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumItems; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[(front + i) % size] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deque q = new Deque(5);
        q.insertLeft(1);
        q.insertRight(2);
        q.display(); // This should print: 1 2
        q.insertLeft(3);
        q.insertRight(4);
        q.display(); // This should print: 3 1 2 4
        q.deleteLeft();
        q.deleteRight();
        q.display(); // This should print: 1 2
    }
}
```

Please do read through and try and understand what's happening on a step-by-step level.

Comment: this is exactly the type of criticism I was looking for, I appreciate you so much man, my brain understood what I wanted but just couldn't write it out properly.